# Issues when choosing between threading and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, joblib

Have an issue with parallelising a code, using joblib.Parallel.
When the backend is `threading` it works as intended as seen below, in terms of results.
Meaning that both `print` show the intended result. When changing the backend to `multiprocessing` the code

1. runs way faster
2. the first print works as intended
3. the second print (which is the final results) is `None`, completely ignoring what it printed

Here is a similar-MWE:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def E_th(i,tt,out_list):
    out_list[tt] =  tt+i
    print(out_list[tt])#>> prints correct results
    return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    time = range(0,10)
    for i in range(0,2):

        out_list = [None]*len(time)
        Parallel(n_jobs=64,backend='threading')(delayed(E_th)(i,tt,out_list) for tt in range(len(time)))

    print(out_list) #>> prints correct results
```

---

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def E_th(i,tt,out_list):
    out_list[tt] =  tt+i
    print(out_list[tt])#>> prints correct results
    return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    time = range(0,10)
    for i in range(0,2):

        out_list = [None]*len(time)
        Parallel(n_jobs=64,backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(E_th)(i,tt,out_list) for tt in range(len(time)))

    print(out_list) #>> prints [None,None..]
```

I'm probably super bad at this so if there is a simple way to understand whats going on and I'll try to fix it :)

Comment: Processes don't share memory. Things written in a child process don't propagate to the parent or siblings. The way you pass in a list that is then supposed to be written to (locking?) by multiple concurrent executions is a bad approach for parallel execution, generally and in Python. Instead, give one task to one parallel job. Return the results from the job and assemble them in the parent.

Comment: I see, so basically i have to return the results and reassemble them by my own right?

Comment: Yes, that's the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreaded: The `out_list` is passed by reference to the child threads. So when they change it it changes in all the threads.

Multiprocess: The `out_list` (in fact the whole memory footprint) is **copied** to the child processes. So when children update the list that change is not propagated up to the parent where the print happens.

Comment: I see, so there is a way of passing the memory, the way you pass indexes in other languages so that it can change each thing? The speed-difference is also weird to me. but it may be due to the server i'm running it on

Comment: It's unclear from your example, but are the tasks CPU-bound? If so, and they are not specifically designed for parallel execution, whey will all hold the GIL (global interpreter lock) of Python when running in one process and simply not run in parallel then.

Comment: Not sure what's CPU-bound :( 
The server i'm sending the job, has nodes, i allocate one node with 64 Cores.